# Difference between common.inc.php and common.php

Tags: php

I would like to know the difference between using common.inc.php or common.php to include files in PHP.

Is this only semantic or is there a reason to use one or the other?

Comment: The difference is that one is shorter than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Using inc.php is something people do to indicate that the file is meant to be included in another script and not accessed directly. As previously stated, it does not affect functionality in any way. Users can still execute the file via the web browser.

It's been a while since I've seen this practice used, as it's mostly used in procedural programs. OOP programs generally have a file associated with each class, with the name matching that of the class, such as `User.php`, `Post.php` etc.